# imagemagick typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined reading 'convert'

Tags: node.js, typescript, imagemagick, nestjs, typeerror

I'm building a pdf conversion service for my nestjs project and I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'convert')`

i believe i'm importing imagemagick correctly here, but calls to `im.convert()` throw this error

```js
import { InjectQueue, Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job, Queue } from 'bull';
import { pdfJob } from './pdfJob';
import im from 'imagemagick';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

@Injectable()
@Processor('pdf')
export class ImagemagickService {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('pdf') private readonly pdfQueue: Queue) {}

  private readonly logger = new Logger(ImagemagickService.name);

  @Process()
  async processPDF(job: Job<pdfJob>) {
    const IMAGE_DIR = `src/../config/img/`;
    const { pdfPath, baseName } = job.data;
    const outputPath = `${IMAGE_DIR}${baseName}.jpg`;

    this.logger.debug(`Converting ${job.data.pdfPath}`);

    try {
      // Promisify the callback of im.convert()
      const images = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Take PDF file and generate individual JPG files
        im.convert(
          [
            '-alpha',
            'remove',
            '-density',
            300,
            '-quality',
            80,
            pdfPath,
            outputPath,
          ],
          async (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              reject(err);
              throw `Couldn't Process ${pdfPath}`;
            } else {
              // Get every file in Temporary Image Directory
              let files = await fs.readdir(IMAGE_DIR);

              // Append directory into filenames
              files = files.map((file) => {
                return IMAGE_DIR + file;
              });

              // We only want the files that match the source pdf's name
              files = files.filter((file) => {
                return file.includes(baseName);
              });

              const output = { pdf: pdfPath, files };

              resolve(output);
            }
          },
        );

        return images;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import it like this instead:

```
import * as im from 'imagemagick';
```

Or use this flag: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#esModuleInterop

Comment: Did they change the api for imagemagick or something? Cause now it's saying i have to initalize imagemagick

Comment: the specific error i'm getting is `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'images' before initialization`

Comment: idk that package, and that's another question. Look at their docs (`npm docs imagemagick`). Did that type error was solved by `import * as im ..`?

Comment: yeah that did the trick. I copied my code verbatim from another project that was vanilla js and I checked and the package version was the same so I have no idea what's going on lol